# Managing an Errors/Status text box in C# WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, status

I'm writing a UI for managing subtitle files, it offers some operations on the file and has an errors/status text box (which is actually a rich text box).
I want to be able to add lines to the text box that indicate the status of a long operation, so I did the following:

`StatusErrors.Text += "Changing time tarted, subtitle file is being processed...\n";
longOperation(StatusErrors);
StatusErrors.Text += "Done\n";`

But the only text I see is "Done" at the end of the operation, why is that?

Comment: You'll need to show the code of that `longOperation` function.

Comment: Try calling Update() on your form (After the changes), the changes are probably updated in the next run.

Comment: Calling StatusErrors.Update() before longOperation() lets you postpone having to use threading for a while.

Answer (score 2):

You only see the "Done" text because you update the UI in the same thread as your long running method, which causes the UI to be locked while the operation is running. Use a `BackgroundWorker`'s `DoWork` event to perform the long running operation and update the status text in the `ProgressChanged` event. An alternative to `BackgroundWorker` would be to call `Application.DoEvents()` after each status update.

Answer (score 0):

Try using
    StatusErrors.AppendText("Error Message");

Answer (score 0):

My guess (only a guess at this point) is there could be problems because you're using '\n' for a newline. Instead try using something like:

```
StatusErrors.Text = "Log line 1" + Environment.NewLine;
```

and then later

```
StatusErrors.AppendText("Log line 2" + Environment.NewLine);
```

Once you have enough text, you'll notice that the RichTextBox doesn't automatically scroll to the end of the text, and doing it automatically can be a hassle. (Also if you do something like `StatusErrors.Text += "Blah blah."` it will reset your position every time, whereas `.AppendText` I don't beleive does this.)  Now, with WPF this is easy, as there's a `ScrollToEnd` function, but with regular WinForms it can be a bit more complicated. I think the most usual method is to do

```
StatusErrors.SelectionLength = 0;
StatusErrors.SelectionStart = StatusErrors.Text.Length - 1;
StatusErrors.ScrollToCaret();
```

This has its issues I think: it puts the TextBox into focus, for instance. An alternative would be something like [the solution in this article](http://bitmatic.com/c/implementing-a-scrolling-richtextbox) which implements it using Windows API functions.

```
// from http://bitmatic.com/c/implementing-a-scrolling-richtextbox

class ScrollingRichTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(
      IntPtr hWnd,
      uint Msg,
      IntPtr wParam,
      IntPtr lParam);

    private const int WM_VSCROLL = 277;
    private const int SB_LINEUP = 0;
    private const int SB_LINEDOWN = 1;
    private const int SB_TOP = 6;
    private const int SB_BOTTOM = 7;

    public void ScrollToBottom()
    {
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_VSCROLL, new IntPtr(SB_BOTTOM), new IntPtr(0));
    }

    public void ScrollToTop()
    {
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_VSCROLL, new IntPtr(SB_TOP), new IntPtr(0));
    }

    public void ScrollLineDown()
    {
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_VSCROLL, new IntPtr(SB_LINEDOWN), new IntPtr(0));
    }

    public void ScrollLineUp()
    {
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_VSCROLL, new IntPtr(SB_LINEUP), new IntPtr(0));
    }
}
```

Also, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137094/managing-an-errors-status-text-box-in-c-winform/7137202#7137202), if you want to write to the log and have it update while you are in a method that is doing a synchronous wait, a possible solution would be to call `Application.DoEvents()` following the write.